# how to solve “No if updown configuration found” for CAN bus interface Linux 18.4.4LTS

Tags: linux, sockets, can-bus

I am trying to get SocketCAN interface working. I've added the slcan0 adapter and trying to run `candump slcan0` at a bit rate I am sure the CAN devices is running at. I dont see any data being printed in the terminal while I am sure CAN device is sending data at 200Hz.

I am using Lawicel CANUSB device and following these steps: http://pascal-walter.blogspot.com/2015/08/installing-lawicel-canusb-on-linux.html

When i am printing system log after binding the interface, I get following information:

```
May 26 10:11:33 username gnome-software[3664]: Failed to load snap icon: local snap has no icon
May 26 10:11:34 username gnome-software[3664]: message repeated 4 times: [ Failed to load snap icon: local snap has no icon]
May 26 10:15:43 username systemd[1]: Started Session 3 of user aceinna.
May 26 10:15:57 username slcand[3923]: starting on TTY device /dev/ttyUSB0
May 26 10:15:57 username slcand[3923]: attached TTY /dev/ttyUSB0 to netdevice slcan0
May 26 10:15:57 username slcand[3923]: netdevice O#015 renamed to slcan0
May 26 10:15:57 username NetworkManager[1543]: <info>  [1590513357.4839] manager: (slcan0): new Generic device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/4)
May 26 10:15:57 username systemd-udevd[3925]: link_config: autonegotiation is unset or enabled, the speed and duplex are not writable.
May 26 10:15:57 username NetworkManager[1543]: <info>  [1590513357.4957] devices added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/slcan0, iface: slcan0)
May 26 10:15:57 username NetworkManager[1543]: <info>  [1590513357.4958] device added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/slcan0, iface: slcan0): no ifupdown configuration found.
May 26 10:16:23 username wpa_supplicant[1539]: wlp59s0: WPA: Group rekeying completed with bc:ee:7b:57:ed:fc [GTK=CCMP]
May 26 10:16:23 username wpa_supplicant[1539]: wlp59s0: WPA: Group rekeying completed with bc:ee:7b:57:ed:fc [GTK=CCMP]
May 26 10:17:01 username CRON[3944]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
```

The problem is, "no ifupdown configuration found"

How do I configure ifupdown configuration for CAN interface?

One of the thing i tried was adding following lines to /etc/network/interfaces

```
auto can0
iface can0 inet manual
        #pre-up ip link set $IFACE type can bitrate 125000 listen-only off
        pre-up /sbin/ip link set $IFACE type can bitrate 250000 triple-sampling on
        up /sbin/ifconfig $IFACE up
        down /sbin/ifconfig $IFACE down
```

Note: I tried using can0 as adapter name when binding the interface to match with interface name in /etc/network/interfaces.

I also updated ifupdown package using

> apt-get ifupdown

Can some one point out to right direction, what should I be looking at?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure how to answer  your question (the answer is software dependent). There is a bad assumption above though; a computer's communication via a serial port is often limited by the amount of interrupts it can handle in a given time. A 200Hz repeat implies a 5ms "delay" between repats; i.e. the task that is repeated MUST run and return earlier than the 5ms there is to the next repeat - I'm not entirely sure that is possible, even with today's speedy computers.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, 5mS is plenty of time. Even RaspberryPi supports this. I am running the same device on raspberryPI at 250000 bitrate and works perfectly fine. My problem has to do with CAN interface setup in Linux Host PC. Some thing is wrong with the Socket Interface and not printing data when using candump.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was originally trying to connect my CAN Transceiver to Linux and print CAN packets using `candump`. I ran into this error message when after I did bind my CAN interface to slcan using `sudo slcand -o -c -f -sX /dev/ttyUSBX slcan0` .

This error was in syslog file. Use the ollowing command `sudo tail -n 10 -f /var/log/syslog` .

As it turns out, when I set the SocketCAN interface to UP in the next step this issue is resolved `sudo ip link set up slcan0` .

I thought *No ifupdown config found error* wasn't letting candump print CAN messages. I was wrong. The problem was CAN termination resistor. My CAN network didn't have termination resistors. As soon as I enabled the Termination resistor in my CAN device I was able to see data using `candump` .

I'm documenting this here in case someone in the future stumbles upon this problem.